# How to check existence using parsley?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, parsley.js

I want to check existence of "Name", "Email" input field, but I can't find the method(or function) in parsleyjs.org...

This is my simple-form and parsley code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
       <%= f.input :name, required: true, autofocus: true%>
       <%= f.input :email, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: "min. 6 characters",
                  input_html: {"parsley-minlength" => 6, "error-container" =>"#errorBlock"} %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true,
                  input_html: {"parsley-equalto" => "#user_password"} %>
      <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "회원 가입" %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<script>
    $("#new_user").parsley({trigger: "keyup",
        errors: {
            errorsWrapper: '<div></div>',
            errorTemplate: '<span></span>'
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you check your browser console for errors??

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to check it...

Comment: If you are using chrome then you can use Ctrl+Shift+J to open developer console

Comment: Or else try this <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {"data-validate" => 'parsley'}) do |f| %> and remove the script at the bottom of form.

Comment: um I think you are misunderstanding my question.. but thank you though.. I already displaied error messages but I want to get another error messages which let me know that the name and email are already taken or not...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question looking at the comments, it seems that you want to leverage Parsley validation to check in your database if email or name is already taken and display a Parsley error accordingly.

To achieve that, you'll need to use Parsley Remote plugin, and its documentation here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote

You'll need to work on your APIs to be able to check backend if these fields values already exist in database, and than integrate parsley.remote.js on top of that.

Best

Comment: I'm thinking that the way to setup the backend API is to have a controller return either a status code or a boolean value in json or something. The docs say it uses the status code, so that's what I'd use. The request should be a 'get' request, and the exact way to return the response would be... 
Right now my api give me a 'missing template' error when I call the appropriate action